# How to get the last inserted value for every id in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to count the unique status from multiple values. Here is my table example

```
Id  Status  OrderId
-------------------
1     1       43
2     2       43
3     1       44
```

Desired output

It should give the count(status) for `Status '1' is 1` and `Status '2' is 1`. But when using count its giving `2 for status '1'`.

Comment: I think you have two 1's in the status column.

Comment: What you tried at all?

Comment: Yes..i have to take the last value of every OrderId

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
count(DISTINCT status)
```

instead of

```
count(status)
```

to get

> unique status from multiple values.

**EDIT:**

If you want to *get* (not *count*) the `Status` value of the  last inserted record for every `OrderId`, then you can do:

```
SELECT Status
FROM (
  SELECT Id,  Status,  OrderId,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId 
                            ORDER BY Id DESC) AS rn
FROM mytable ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: But if we use COUNT(DISTINCT Status), it is as good as DISTINCT of STATUS Column. I mean for every status, we will have COUNT(STATUS) as 1

Comment: @PareshJ It depends on what the OP wants to `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Actually its a part of my query..i have tried this query with multiple joins.I have to count the last insert record for every order id

Comment: @Giorgos: Yes, which is why i am confused what exactly OP intends to get as output.

Comment: I cant get you @PareshJ

Comment: @Priya Check my edit. I'm not sure any more about what you actually want.

Comment: @Priya Glad I was able to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the last `status` for each order:

```
with cte as(select *, row_number() 
                       over(partition by OrderID order by Id desc) from TableName)
select * from cte where rn = 1
```

Or:

```
select * from (select *, row_number() 
                       over(partition by OrderID order by Id desc) from TableName) t
where rn = 1
```